# Difficulties in routes with translations in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Good afternoon !

I have problems with file routes , I am using this format to recieve the view

```
   Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
    {

        Route::get(
            '/{contact}',
            function () {
                return View::make('main');
            }
        );
    });
```

but I prefer using the following instruction

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Could anyone help to me for substitute the first methodology for the second ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a controller file in your `app/Http/Controllers` folder called `HomeController.php`. You can do that manually or by running the following command in your app directory:

```sh
php artisan make:controller HomeController --plain
```

In the newly generated controller you need to add the `index` method that returns your view like you did in your route closure:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('main');
    }
}
```

And that's about all there is to it, you can now use the route definition `Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');` and it will run the code in your `index` action.

In the future it would really pay off to [read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers) first, because in most cases it offers all the information you need.

Comment: Yes I know , I think I don't know explain correctly , I have problem because with the first methodology I don't know how the secndone option , I am using translate files and I found information with the other format , and I think it's horrible.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying you want to replace the definition `Route::get('/{contact}', function () { ... });` that contains a closure, with a definition that calls a controller action like so `Route::get('/{contact}', 'HomeController@index');`? If not, please try explaining better because it's pretty hard to understand.

Comment: Yes , it is  , i don't know the specific name about this sorry :)